# How to convert audio data into NSString in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, nsstring, nsdata

I would like to convert audio data into NSString.

I have audio data and it is not bull. But when i convert audio into NSString that converting string  is null. I am using following code.....

```
NSString *audioStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:audioData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Where i am wrong i don't understand. Please help me any one.

Comment: I did not know that audio data was encoded using UTF-8. And what are you trying to do here anyways? I can't imagine a scenario where you want to display binary data in a string. Do you want text recognition?

Comment: @JustSid: Yes. I want text recognition. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for `'Speech to Text'` recognition, you can try

1. [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
2. [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/speech.recognition)

Also, if you just want to dictate to UITextField or UITextView, you can use the built-in option for speech-to-text.